Error: Deployment failed: Error: Status: 400. Message:
can anyone help with this, i was trying to deploy my spring-boot app on aws beanstalk using git action and i encounter this error, IAM user has all the necessary permission like:
AdministratorAccess | AWS managed - job function | Directly
| AmazonEC2FullAccess | AWS managed | Directly
| AmazonS3FullAccess | AWS managed | Directly
| AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess | AWS managed | Directly
| AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy | AWS managed | Directly
| AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier | AWS managed | Directly
| IAMUserChangePassword
and the S3 bucket has public acesss
Run einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v14
Beanstalk-Deploy: GitHub Action for deploying to Elastic Beanstalk.
https://github.com/einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy
***** Input parameters were: *****
Application: simplee
Environment: simplee-stage
Version Label: simplee-stage-2024-07-17
service/actions/runs/9981401705/job/27587041557#step:9:18)T22-01-52-897Z
Version description:
AWS Region: il-central-1
File: deploy.zip
AWS Access Key: 20 characters long, starts with A
AWS Secret Key: 40 characters long, starts with P
Wait for deployment: true
Recovery wait time: 30
Uploading file to bucket elasticbeanstalk-il-central-1-7303354329
service/actions/runs/9981401705/job/27587041557#step:9:25)
Error: Deployment failed: Error: Status: 400. Message:
Solution and reason why its happened

Resolved.
Problem was caused by beanstalk-deploy@v14, this version does not support il-central-1 region. updated the version and now it is working

Why not promote this to an answer?
